# JavaWebStart and resources like images and files

Tags: java, image, import, report, java-web-start

I have a doubt. I am using javawebstar in a swing project. In my app i have some images that I use to improve the design and a file .xls to show a report. I am using the method `getClass().getResource("")` to locate the images and I realized that my app try to find the resource in the web server using something like this: jar:http://www... . I thought that all resource would be sought in the local computer where the app was installed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The app. will download the resources when needed and cache them on the local disks.

For *security reasons* the URL shown in the console will *always point to the server*, even for a trusted app. for which all the resources are cached.